# Is it possible to republish Android old app as new Flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, google-play

I have one Android application already published on Google Play long back. Now I want to republish it with Flutter version. Just wanted to know is it possible to replace old application with the Flutter version ?

I am going to completely re-write the app in Flutter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many things to consider other than a Key which you have used earlier with the account.

Of course, Keystore and the Key used to sign for the previous version is the most relevant entity you must have for updating the app.
As per the Google standards you should mention all the notable changes made to the app in the playstore console (This is mainly for the existing users to consider the app-update). You should be increasing the versionCode in your app (build.gradle) from the previous version to update your apk.

There may be some additional surveys / questions introduced by Google in order to attain certificate/rating to your new app if you are using playstore after a very long time.
There are different levels of update options available in playstore console (manual release, region wise release, partial release. etc) make complete use of everything. Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it should be possible. The only thing is that package name off new app should same as old app. And it should be also signed with same key as old version

Comment: It works, and you can still access the old application data (DB, shared prefs).